# cd command behaves differently on same context in Red

Tags: rebol, red

See latest lines: from same context %/C/ directory, doing "cd rebol" works in one case and doesn't work in another case:

```
    >> what-dir
    == %/C/rebol/
    >> cd ..
    == %/C/
    >> what-dir
    == %/C/
    >> cd rebol
    == %/C/rebol/
    >> what-dir
    == %/C/rebol/
    >> cd /
    *** Script Error: / operator is missing an argument
    *** Where: catch
    *** Stack:  

    >> what-dir
    == %/C/rebol/
    >> cd ..
    == %/C/
    >> cd rebol
    == %/C/rebol/
    >> cd %/
    == %/
    >> what-dir
    == %/C/
    >> cd rebol
    *** Access Error: cannot open: %/rebol/
    *** Where: do
    *** Stack: cd change-dir cause-error  

    >>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not on Windows right now, so I can't test it, but I believe there is problem here:

```
>> cd %/
== %/
>> what-dir
== %/C/
>> cd rebol
(...)
```

`cd %/` changes directory to the root directory and that is definitely `%/C/` as reported by `what-dir`.
So I guess `what-dir` is reporting wrong directory. I will try to add info later, when I will check it on Windows, or maybe someone will be faster and confirms it :)
You can also try `read %/` to see what's there (it should be block of Windows drives).

Answer (score 1):

There seems  to be a difference between **what-dir** and **pwd**

```
>> ls
    C/                   D/                   E/                   Z/               
>> pwd
%/
>> what-dir
== %/C/
>>
```

**pwd** and **cd** (change-dir) use **system/options/path** leading to the issue, that should be reported.

**/** is the infix operator for a division. It will lead always to this error message if not in the rigth context

```
>> /
*** Script Error: / operator is missing an argument
*** Where: catch
*** Stack:  

>> 10 / 5
== 2
>>
```